# How to import .sql dump file from MySQL to SQLite WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, sqlite-net

I am developing a WPF application.

I created a local SQLite database (using System.Data.SQLite):

```
SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db");
```

And need to fill it with a MySQL database located in a server. I already got to download the .sql dump file from the server, the problem is that how can i import this file to my local database?

I already searched on the web and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855559/import-mysql-dump-file-to-sqlite) the problem is that this mention android...

Any information is welcome.

UPDATE 1:
Opening the .sql file and executing a SQLite command does not import the .sql, here is my code:

```
string lines = "";
try
{
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(databaseFile))
      {
            lines += sr.ReadToEnd();
      }
 } catch (Exception)
 {
 }

SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=test.db");
conn.Open();

var command = conn.CreateCommand();
command.CommandText = lines;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

The application crashes with the next error:

> Additional information: SQL logic error or missing database
>
> near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error

Comment: Possible Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1191375/c-how-to-import-sql-script-into-database-programmatically

Open a connection to the SQLite and execute the SQL file.

Comment: @juanvan it didn´t helped

Comment: If you want to continue down the SQL path, you will have to edit the SQL as SQLite's SQL is not the same as MySQL's (see https://sqlite.org/lang.html). For each "syntax error" you see, you'll have to take some remedial action; you'll probably have to learn more about MySQL's SQL in the process. I'd also use sqlite3 (the command-line interpreter) as part of the process. If it's admissible, a simpler alternative might be to export to TSV and then import it.

Answer (score 0):

They are different SQL dialects so that solution is going to give you quite a bit of a headache.
If this is a one time activity I would use a (free) tool like:
http://www.sql-workbench.net/

that has a Data Pump tool that allows you to move data across different databases.

Comment: I can only use php to do this